# Really Slow CSS Animations (worse on Chrome browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I am having issues with lag when using a combination of two CSS animations. The first one animates text shadow on a text, and the second animation is animating two SVG's in the background. On Firefox it doesn't lag very much, but on Chrome it's really bad. [Here is a video of it](https://www.loom.com/share/a5c534a777ed4c478401074010eeaab3).

Here is a snippet:

```css
/*NEON TEXT CODE*/

#flicker {
  animation: flicker-text 1.5s infinite alternate;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes flicker-text {
  0%,
  18%,
  22%,
  25%,
  53%,
  57%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 11px #fff, 0 0 19px #fff, 0 0 40px #B0D9DD, 0 0 80px #B0D9DD, 0 0 90px #B0D9DD, 0 0 100px #B0D9DD, 0 0 150px #B0D9DD;
  }
  20%,
  24%,
  55% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}


/*OCEAN AND WAVE CODE*/

#ocean-container-vs-code {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.ocean {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #015871;
}

.wave {
  background: url(//dd7tel2830j4w.cloudfront.net/f1659025056348x434203136138475760/wave.svg) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  top: -198px;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 198px;
  -webkit-animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -175px;
  -webkit-animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -0.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -0.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes swell {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes swell {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ocean-container-vs-code" style="background:linear-gradient(90deg, #faf0cd, #fab397)">
  <div class="ocean">
    <div class="wave"></div>
    <div class="wave"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="flicker">This is some test text</p>
```

Does anyone have any insight on why combining these two animations causes severe lag? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Pay attention to when the text flickers. On the moment the text flickers, the waves lag.

Comment: animating box-shadows is already hardware intensive, combining it with the large svg transform made it worse. I suggest replacing the box-shadow with a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element that will replicate the effect

Comment: Your example renders nice and smooth for me. Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 11

Comment: @KyloDev Alright, that's a good suggestion. I'll check that out :)

Comment: @phuzi Pay attention to when the text flickers, it slows the down the waves. Also keep in mind the code snippet is really small compared to the actual production site, so it's less bad (but I still notice it). Check the video to see what I mean!

Comment: Yeah, I saw the video. I just don't experience the same from your (relatively tiny) snippet.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).